Printing Span and trace id in log for GCP Tracing
I read though several pieces of documentation and they all seem to be missing an important detail. The log format and not listing all the dependencies needed. For example like this one: https://spring-gcp.saturnism.me/app-dev/observability/trace.
I will post all the needed dependencies I needed to get the span and trace ID to printed locally. But as of right now it is still not working on GCP and I done everything stated in the url listed above.
if you are using a logback file it will look something like this
<springProfile name="local">
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>[traceId: %X{traceId} spanId: %X{spanId}] %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</springProfile>

this is the part that is not working on GCP
<springProfile name="!local">
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
            <pattern>%X{traceId} %X{spanId}  %date{ISO8601} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg %mdc{context}</pattern>
            <fieldNames>
                <timestamp>timestamp</timestamp>
                <level>severity</level>
                <mdc>context</mdc>
                <message>msg</message>
            </fieldNames>
            <customFields>{"product": "products","component": "dev":,"version": "NA}"}</customFields>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

pom.xml
    <!-- ............................................................... -->
    <!--                            GCP Tracing                          -->
    <!-- ............................................................... -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-trace</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-http</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-tracing</artifactId>
        <version>${micrometer}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-core</artifactId>
        <version>${micrometer}</version>
    </dependency>

If you want you can make experiment with the tags within your application.
@SpanName("processing")
public void processing(final JsonNode document, @SpanTag("locale") final Locale locale) {

For me, having this setup started to print out locally but on GCP, I still get nothing. However I am getting the spanId and traceId there too. It is just in a place I think it is not suppose to be.
context: {
  spanId: "2a2890a7490471c6"
  traceId: "660a62f0863ea5d02a2890a7490471c6"
}

Here is a copy of the whole log
{"timestamp":"2024-04-01T09:47:45.56478+02:00","@version":"1","msg":"Finished products extraction for locale: us_EN","logger_name":"ees.product.form.application.api.rest.ProductController","thread_name":"http-nio-8080-exec-8","severity":"INFO","level_value":20000,"context":{"traceId":"660a6696875a5e7799ad1501953804f3","spanId":"fb05dc2918131456"},"product":"ees","component":"qrt","stage":"NA","version":"NA","region":"NA"}

--- update----
<springProfile name="!local">
        <appender name="STDOUT"
                  class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
            <encoder>
                <fieldNames>
                    <timestamp>timestamp</timestamp>
                    <level>severity</level>
                    <mdc>context</mdc>
                    <message>msg</message>
                </fieldNames>
                <pattern> %X{traceId}: %X{spanId} %d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %magenta([%thread]) %highlight(%-5level) %logger{36}.%M - %msg%n"</pattern>
            </encoder>
        </appender>

        <springProperty scope="context" name="logAppender" source="log.appender"/>

        <root level="INFO}">
            <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        </root>
    </springProfile>

This resulted in the traceId and spanId being printed in the logs but Tracing is still not working on GCP.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
